# Varnish 4.1.9 used high memory

Tags: linux, centos, memory, varnish

I have a few cache servers which are running varnish 4.0.5. I have dedicated 6GB of Ram to varnish on all servers. The Operating system is Centos6.9 and all servers have 8GB of total memory. I recently installed varnish 4.1.9 on a CentOS6.9. Version 4.0.5 is removed from the repositories and I had to install version 4.1.9. The strange problem is that the maximum used memory of Varnish on the other servers with varnish 4.0.5 does not go beyond 2.5GB after about 3 months, but on the new server after about 8 hours the maximum memory usage of varnish is about 5GB!!! I checked the memory usage with top command. The varnish vcl file and the traffics for all servers are almost the same. has memory allocation mechanism been changed in the new versions or something else happened to varnish?! Any help is appreciated in this issue.

Comment: How do you measure memory usage? Is the traffic comparable? You have allowed Varnish to use 6GB of memory; you can't complain if it does. In general, `varnishstat` is your friend.

Comment: Thank you @Peter. I measure the memory with top command. But as you said `varnishstat` is the perfect tool to measure the memory usage and other parameters. I modified the .vcl file and restarted varnish and monitor the memory usage with `varnishstat`. Now I think everything is OK. The former .vcl was caching a lot of unnecessary things :D.